# Signification of "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" in term of the used Google Map API version

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the signification of "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" in term of the used Google Map API version?
In the Google Map documentation, it defines v=n.mm with by examples v=3.34 or v=3.35.
But nothing explains when you use v=3.
What does it mean please?

Answer (score 1):

That used to be how google suggested requesting the "release" version of the API (before the weekly/quarterly versions were added).

from [an old version of the documentation on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611023838/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions):

> **For regular applications**
>   We recommend specifying v=3 in your bootstrap request. This means that you always get the current release version of the Google Maps JavaScript API that has already been subjected to a large volume of traffic and had necessary bug fixes applied. In most cases you should expect that no action is necessary when a version rolls over.

Comment: Thanks. I did not understand that it is a bad specification to use v=3. So that means it is like v=weekly. If the version of Google Map API change (v3 to v4 by example) and if I let v=3, so that means I will think use v3 Google MAP API version but it will be wrong cause I will use the latest version v4 Google MAP API. Is it correct?